# Jquery Accessing Heavily Nested Input

Tags: jquery, html, alert, nested, contact-form-7

I am trying to access an input that is heavily nested within a group of `<span></span>` and a `<p></p>`. I cannot change the way it is nested so the only thing I can do is try to find a way to access it. below is the way my code is nested. (cannot be changed). inb4 my JQuery is enabled I have done some test alerts beforehand.

```
<div id="chargeRequest ">
    <p>Chargeable Request - If selected fill section below<br>
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap checkbox-397">
            <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox">
                <span class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-397[]" value="yes">
                    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">yes
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

---

### Attempts

I am trying to get the JQuery to throw a simple alert when the check box is ticked but I cannot seem to access it. Below are the things I have tried

The first example I was going off the outermost div and seeing if it could find and input with the property of checked. Nothing seemed to happen here

```
if ($('#chargeRequest').find('input').prop('checked')) {
    alert('test');
}
```

The second attempt i was using the span class one layer in too try and then find an input. once it ahd found one it checked if it was checked. Nopthign happened here also.

```
if ($('.checkbox-397').find('input')) {
    if (this.is('checked')) {
        alert('test');
    }
}
```

The third attempt I got despererate and tried to do a large nesting chain. This did not work see below 2 attempts at nesting.

```
if ($('#chargeRequest>p>span>span>input:checked')) {
        alert('test');
    }
}

if ($('#chargeRequest>p>span>span>input').is(':checked')) {
        alert('test');
    }
}
```

the method above I also tried `.prop()` and it ried both without the `>`

Comment: Where are you running these `if` statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your first try should work, just one thing, remove the space from id.

`<div id="chargeRequest ">` should be `<div id="chargeRequest">`

Also you can select input like this:

```
 if ($('#chargeRequest input').prop('checked')) {
    alert('test');
}
```

see the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/nqfvoubv/)

```js
$('input').click(function() {

  if ($('#chargeRequest input').prop('checked')) {
    alert('test');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chargeRequest">
  <p>Chargeable Request - If selected fill section below
    <br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap checkbox-397">
            <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox">
                <span class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
                    <input type="checkbox"  name="checkbox-397[]" value="yes" />
                    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">yes
                    </span>
    </span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: it only started when I removed the space. Thank-you. Such a silly error, gets the best of us ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is the  space in the id of your selector in the markup:

```
<div id="chargeRequest ">
```

change it to:

```
<div id="chargeRequest">
```

find it in the test below.

```js
if ($('#chargeRequest').find('input').prop('checked')) {
    alert('test');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chargeRequest">
    <p>Chargeable Request - If selected fill section below<br>
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap checkbox-397">
            <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox">
                <span class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-397[]" value="yes" checked>
                    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">yes
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```